# Filter JSON(API) with Typescript in Angular6

Tags: typescript, angular6

## **Filtering a JSON** which im getting from a API call(GET)...

Unable to filter the JSON based on particular item(group)

I'm getting the JSON and storing it to an element(of same  JSON structure)
filtering it using

this.newelement = element.filter( task => task.item === item1 )

But returning NULL

**JSON structure:**

```
export class stru {

"date": string;
"items": string;

    }
```

**Service called to GET API:**

```
getstru(): Observable<stru[]> {
    return this.http
    .get(
      API_URL + "stru/"
    )
    .pipe(map((response: Response) => < stru[] > response.json()));
}
```

**Component.ts:**

```
  this.Service.getstru().subscribe(res => {
      this.test= res;
      this.ledger= this.test;
      this.sortedflt=this.ledger.filter(task => task.items === "item1");
      console.log("filteres",this.sortedflt);
  })
```

Comment: What's in this.ledger? And is it possible 'item1' is not in your array (although it's probably not that because you would get an empty array).

Comment: Can you post the json that you are getting?

Comment: Sorry for the question its working properly.... Thanks for your response